# Jenkins Master to slave communication; port forwarding

Tags: networking, jenkins

I am a newbie to Jenkins and to networking, and i have a basic question here ... 
I have Server X with Jenkins Master installed and running , and in an other network(w) I have a machine B witch doesn't have dedicated external IP , so basically it gets the external IP address of the network.

I know that the slave should connect to the master through a specific port .
but how will the communication work from Master to Slave ?  i suppose i need some forwarding rules to that specific Ip of machine B,Do I ?,
How can i get this to work ?
Please guide me, I hope my question is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

The JNLP connection, once initiated, is a persistent connection that is bi-directional.  As long as you can connect one of the ways, then the connection should persist.  The network that hides the slave should take care of NAT (Network address translation) and should keep a record of what internal system (the slave) is connected to what external resources (the Jenkins master).  If it doesn't work, then there are some other problems keeping the two from connecting.